# How to get an element at specified index from c++ List

Tags: c++, list, get

I have a `list`:

```
list<Student>* l;
```

and I would like to get an element at a specified index. Example:

```
l->get(4)//getting 4th element
```

Is there a function or method in `list`  which enables it to do so?

Comment: This begs the question _why_? Are you sure you want a list?

Comment: On top of what @LightnessRacesinOrbit said, if you are sure you need a `list`, are you sure you want a *pointer* to a `list`?

Answer (score 43):

`std::list` does not have a random access iterator, so you have to step 4 times from the front iterator. You can do this manually or with [std::advance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance), or [std::next](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) in C++11, but bear in mind that both O(N) operations for a list.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <list>

....

std::list<Student> l; // look, no pointers!
auto l_front = l.begin();

std::advance(l_front, 4);

std::cout << *l_front << '\n';
```

**Edit**: The original question asked about vector too. This is now irrelevant, but may be informative nonetheless:

`std::vector` does have random access iterators, so you can perform the equivalent operation in O(1) via the `std::advance`, [std::next](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) if you have C++11 support, the `[]` operator, or the `at()` member function:

```
std::vector<Student> v = ...; 
std::cout << v[4] << '\n';    // UB if v has less than 4 elements
std::cout << v.at(4) << '\n'; // throws if v has less than 4 elements
```

Comment: A warning for anyone thinking of using vectors, resizing them requires either `copy` or `noexcept move` constructors.  If it isn't super time sensitive, lists can save you a lot of data-management headaches.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a `get()` function that returns the `_i`th `Student` in `_list`.

```
Student get(list<Student> _list, int _i){
    list<Student>::iterator it = _list.begin();
    for(int i=0; i<_i; i++){
        ++it;
    }
    return *it;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want random access to elements, you should use a `vector` and then you can use `[]` operator to get the 4th element.

```
vector<Student> myvector (5); // initializes the vector with 5 elements`
myvector[3]; // gets the 4th element in the vector
```

Answer (score 1):

For `std::vector` you can use

`myVector.at(i)` //retrieve ith element

Comment: I hope this is no more relevant as you changed your post from list or vector to just list

Comment: note that this solution involves a run-time array bounds check, therefore it is likely to be slower than using `operator[]`.

Comment: @Andrei It may take more time, but then its handled gracefully

Comment: If the container size is greater than n, the function never throws exceptions (no-throw guarantee).
Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.