# Getting a specific element from Queue

Tags: c++

I have a queue:
`queue<string> saves`. I need to use it's ability to remove elements from the front. Is there a way to get a specific element in the queue like the 5th one?
Neither `saves.at(4)` nor `saves[4]` works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The entire point of a queue is you can only see and get the item, if any, waiting at the out end. Anything that allows you to see any other values in the queue is not a queue.

Wanting to see inside the queue suggests that you do not want a queue. Try a [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) instead.

Comment: Or a `std::vector` like almost everyone needs. (+1)

Comment: I know about vector but it misses the ability to pop the front element. deque seems to be just what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: @Vorac `vector` makes an excellent stack, but a poor queue. When you insert at the beginning of the `vector` you incur a O(N) operation moving all of the items in the `vector` to make room for the new item. `deque` allows amortized O(1) insertion because it's a chain of blocks. Every now and then you take a hit from adding a new block just like every now and then you force a `vector` resize adding an item. On the other hand, you lose a bit of speed iterating and randomly accessing items because you no longer have one contiguous data store.

Comment: @FabriceSchöneberger `vector` lacks `push_front` and `pop_front` methods for the reason covered above. They are expensive operations, and the library designers didn't want users of the `vector` to easily write code that play to `vector`'s weaknesses. Leaving out those methods forces users to look for different solutions, maybe as simple as a different library container, rather than blindly incur a performance penalty.

Comment: @user4581301 I concur with every point you make! I was just pointing out that "if you don't know what you need, use a vector(aka modern array). Contiguous storage is extremely efficient - even for 'drop an element in the middle' operations."

Answer (score 0):

If you can try another data structure, try [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list),

But in this case, List Does not have 'at' method

So if you have to access element with index, see also [How to get an element at specified index from c++ List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747591/how-to-get-an-element-at-specified-index-from-c-list)